# Vue.js this.$nextTick() doesn't seems to wait for dom rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm facing a problem using nextTick() in Vue.

Here is the template code :
In the template :

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="editing">
      <span ref="theInput"
            contenteditable="true">{{ someValue }}</span>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <span>{{ someValue }}</span>
    </div>
    ...
</template>
```

And the script code :

```js
data() {
  editing: false
}
...
methods: {
  toggle() {
    this.editing = ! this.editing;
    if (this.editing) {
      this.$refs.theInput.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

Of course `this.$refs.theInput` is not rendered yet when I ask to focus in it.

So far, the only way I've figured out how to make it work is to add a timeout, which is a very bad solution :

```js
methods: {
  toggle() {
    this.editing = ! this.editing;
    if (this.editing) {
      setTimeout(() => this.$refs.theInput.focus(), 100)
    }
  }
}
```

Trying to make it more clean I tried this, but the result is the same :

```js
methods: {
  toggle() {
    this.editing = ! this.editing;
    if (this.editing) {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs.theInput.focus();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Shouldn't nextTick wait for the dom to render before trying to focus on theInput ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Found it, $nextTick wasn't at the good place. Move it like this works :

```js
methods: {
  toggle() {
    this.editing = ! this.editing;
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      if (this.editing) {
        this.$refs.theInput.focus();
      };
    });
  }
}
```